# Upload File parameter not coming through to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, upload

I am fairly new to Rails and have been making steady progress on a Mobile Web App I am working on for our local high school but have run into an issue which I am stumped on.  I am hoping the collective knowledge here will point me in the right direction.

I have a model for the school athletes (first name, last name, height, weight, graduation years, - standard stuff) which is working (CRUD via standard scaffold generation) and now I want to add the ability to import records via CSV upload.

In an effort to not reinvent the wheel, I am following [this example from Rich on Rails](http://richonrails.com/articles/importing-csv-files).  To get familiar with it, I created a separate Rail project and followed the example and it all works as expected.  Great.  Now to integrate into my existing project.

Everything seems to integrate fine with one exception - the CSV file is never passed to my model in the params I cannot figure out why.  I am sure it is something obvious but I have stared at this problem for several hours and am unable to see what I am doing wrong.

Here is a portion of my Athletes controller:

```
class AthletesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_athlete, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /athletes
  # GET /athletes.json
  def index
    @athletes = Athlete.all.order(:lastname, :firstname)
  end

  # POST /athletes/import
  # POST /athletes/import.json
  def import
    logger.info(params.to_yaml)
    begin
      Athlete.import(params[:file])
      redirect_to page_path('admin'), notice: "Athletes imported."
    rescue
      redirect_to page_path('admin'), notice: "Invalid CSV file format."
    end
  end

  # GET /athletes/1
  # GET /athletes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /athletes/new
  def new
    @athlete = Athlete.new
  end

  # GET /athletes/1/edit
  def edit
  end
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  # an athlete can be on more than one team
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams, through: :athletes

  require 'csv'

  ##  CSV import
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      athlete_hash = row.to_hash # exclude the ? field
      athlete = Athlete.where(id: athlete_hash["id"])

      if athlete.count == 1
        athlete.first.update_attributes
      else
        Athlete.create!(athlete_hash)
      end # end if !athlete.nil?
    end # end CSV.foreach
  end # end self.import(file)
```

I've added this onto my index view for testing, later on it will be in an admin area:

```
<div>
<h3>Import a CSV File</h3>
  <%= form_tag import_athletes_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

No matter what I do, I never get the value of the *file_field_tag* to come through to the controller.  If I add other fields using *text_field_tag* they come through as expected but the *file_field_tag* value never does.

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: "✓"
authenticity_token: it3yBxBnzA4UQ/NILP5GNoYJeO5dyg+Z+VfhE/C6p7k=
commit: Import CSV
action: import
controller: athletes

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I am stumped - if anyone has any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong, I would be grateful.  I have about 300 athletes which I want to import and have no desire to type them in.

Comment: try run `import` action without `begin...rescue..end` block, 99% bug here.

Comment: I commented out the begin/rescue/end and it didn't make any difference - actually, not quite true.  I had an error due to the :file parameter being unknown.  Right now the only thing I have in play is the **logger.info(params.to_yaml)** to see what is available within **params** and there is no **file** value.

Comment: Your file get uploaded properly ?

Comment: No - I would expect to see something like this:

{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"mGm6jN7uvoRVjVbSDE/vpprIQnpjiL60s4rETHT9mPA=",
 "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xaa974dc @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140530-4261-z8fb9x>,
 @original_filename="stg_pound.csv",
 @content_type="text/csv",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"stg_pound.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n">,
 "commit"=>"Import"}

As I noted in my original question, the dump of params does not contain the "file" field.

Comment: What gem you are using to save file `paperclip` or `carrierwave`

Comment: try use tempfile `file.tempfile.path` in `CSV.foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out because I am using jQuery Mobile for my framework, I need to add "data-ajax=false" to my form tag.  This change to my form allowed the file parameter to be visible in the controller:

```
<h3>Import a CSV File</h3>
  <%= form_tag(import_athletes_path, { :multipart => true, :'data-ajax' => false }) do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

A short while ago I recalled reading something about file uploads and jQuery Mobile not working by default.  It is due to the standard AJAX navigation employed by jQM.